# Expanding all subfolders in project home directory using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgs, qgis-browser

In the QGIS browser, I would love to have all subfolders and ESRI GDBs to be expanded such that I can search for specific datasets via the browser search in the QGIS GUI.
Currently, I struggle with finding the project directory.

So far, I figured out the code to set the project home directory like this:

```py
projectModel = iface.browserModel()
browserTreeView = QgsBrowserTreeView()
QGISproject = QgsProject.instance()
QGISproject.setPresetHomePath(r"P:\folder\subfolder1\subfolder2\projectFolder")
```

and initialize a QgsBrowserModel and get the drive Items of it:

```
browserModel = QgsBrowserModel()
browserTreeView.setModel(projectModel)
browserModel.initialize()
browserModel.driveItems()
```

Thus, it returns the drives C: to P:.

How can I access the project folder of the browserModel?

With `browserModel.rootItems()` I tried to get all browser items listet. However, QGIS then crashed.
Edit: With QGIS 3.34.4 the function works fine.

---

In between, I tried some differenct code to expand all subdirectories of the now set project folder. However, it does not work.

```
projectModel = iface.browserModel()

QGISproject = QgsProject.instance()
QGISproject.setPresetHomePath(r"P:\folder\subfolder1\subfolder2\projectFolder")
projDir = QGISproject.homePath()

browserTreeView = QgsBrowserTreeView()
browserTreeView.setModel(projectModel)

projDirIdx = projectModel.findPath(projDir)
browserTreeView.expand(projDirIdx)
# alternatively:
#browserTreeView.expandRecursively(projDirIdx, depth=-1)
```

Comment: @Matt Done. Sorry and thanks!

Comment: No problem, and thanks. Giving an answer is much easier when all the relevant information is included. Incidentally, `browserModel.rootItems()` works fine when I test it (QGIS 3.34.3) and I do not experience a crash.

Comment: Alright, with QGIS 3.34, I can replicate it. In the meantime, I tried some different code that I added in the post. However, it does not work anyways. Any ideas are highly appreciated!

Comment: I am keen to help you, but honestly, I do not really understand your issue/problem as well as the main task. Can you please explain one more time?

Comment: Sure! I want to expand all subfolders of a specified project home directory  in the QGIS browser window. For this, I already figured out how to set the project home path (see code above, l. 1-4). What I struggle with is to access the browser tree view and get the expand function working on the correct item. Is this more explicit?